# Where is the following piecewise function continuous and differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis

Where is the following piecewise function continuous and differentiable at $n=1$?
$$
f(n) =
\begin{cases}
an+b,  & \text{if $n$ $\le$ 1} \\[2ex]
2n^2, & \text{if $n$  $\gt$ 1}
\end{cases}
$$

My attempt:

For a f to be continuous at $n=1$ we require the left hand and right hand limit as $n \rightarrow 1$ to be equal. So for the first part, would the answer be $a+b=2?$ Would this be a valid answer?
What would I have to do for the differentiable part?

Comment: $a+b=2$ is a needed condition for your answer, For the differentiable part, one could look at their derivatives and set them equal for $n=1$. See what you get

Comment: For the differentiable part, I have got $a=4$ therefore $b=-2$ would that be correct? Also if the question was asking when is the function continuous, would that be for $any$ $a+b=2?$

Comment: Your $a,b$ makes sense. For the second part, for continuity, $a+b=2$ is sufficient, because you are "connecting" both graphs in that manner, But for a smooth transition, you want differentiability which is guaranteed for the values you calculated

Comment: Allright then..